# Submultiplicative property of matrices

Tags: matrices, lipschitz-functions, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I want to find the Lipschitz constant of the function $g(Bx)$, where $g:\mathbb{R}^{m} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a K-Lipschitz function, $B \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ is a matrix, and $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is fixed.

First consider a function $f(B) = Bx$. We can determine its Lipschitz constant  as follows
\begin{equation*}
L = \max_{B_1 \neq B_2} \frac{\|B_1 x - B_2 x\|}{\| B_1 - B_2\|} = \max_{B \neq 0} \frac{\|B x\|}{\| B\|} = \|x\|
\end{equation*}

Using this result, I can define the Lipschitz norm of $g(Bx)$ as $K \|x\|$. I was wondering when $B$ is a vector instead of a matrix, $B = y^\top$,  I will still get $\|x\|$ using the above reasoning. However, Cauchy-Schwartz inequality suggests that the $L = \|x\|_{*}$, where $\|\|_{*}$ is the dual norm. So the question boils down to, if the following submulticative property is true, $\|B x\| \stackrel{?}{\leq} \|B\| \|x\|_{*}$.

Comment: Sorry, what is $g$ exactly?

Comment: I added more details to the post.